# DiscoverMeteor: Commit 2-2

Tags: meteor

Right after adding bootstrap (after commit 2-1), the font of the main page changed, even though microscope.css is still empty. I could not find any other stylesheets in the microscope directory. How was the style applied?

Answer (score 2):

After having meteorite install the bootstrap package (`mrt add bootstrap`), you will have a new `bootstrap` directory in the top-level `packages` directory.  The styling is applied from there.

You may be used to including css/js files in the `<head>` of your html files.  In meteor, css and js files are collected throughout your project and loaded automatically (in production, they're also minified).  This is handy, but you may get into issues with the order in which the files are loaded, so keep in mind the rules for load order, [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp).